# Transform "ambigous" factor to Posixct value

Tags: r

this is an extract with some dates.

```
df<-structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("05JUL2014:00:00:00", 
"07FEB2014:00:00:00", "10JUL2012:00:00:00", "19APR1998:00:00:00", 
"22DEC2010:00:00:00"), class = "factor")
```

I would like to transform this as Date or Posixct.

I Tried this :

```
as.POSIXct(df,"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

but it dont seems to be the good solution. can anyone show me my mistake ?

edit : i also tried this:

```
as.POSIXct(df, format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

but I obtain

```
NA NA NA NA
```

Re edit :

```
as.POSIXct("07FEB2014:00:00:00", format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

return

```
NA
```

but

```
as.POSIXct("072014:00:00:00", format = "%d%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

return

```
"2014-09-07 CEST"
```

%b dont seems to understand "FEB" , my computer use "french" Locale... (but it also dont seems to understand FEV or JAN (instead of FEB and JAN)

Final? edit

I found a solution by using this function :

```
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

I dont realy understand why, but it's seems to be ok.

thks

Comment: You are almost there, just add `format`, as in `as.POSIXct(df, format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")`, otherwise you are passing the `format` to the `tz` argument. Or just do `as.Date(df, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")`, as you don't have any real values for day time

Comment: dont work on my computer I got NA NA NA NA.

Comment: That's is odd. Are you sure you've added `format`? Did you try with `as.Date`?

Comment: David's solution works for me.

Comment: I thinks the probleme come from my Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") : "French_France.1252" variable...

Comment: Oh, you found a solution already. Didn't see your edit. Never mind then

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your LOCALE environment to the generic "C" which is probably defaulting to English months:

Need to convert to charter before using strptime or as.POSIXct:

```
dfc <- as.character(df)
as.POSIXct(dfc, format="%d%B%Y:%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-02-07 PST" "2012-07-10 PDT" "2014-07-05 PDT" "1998-04-19 PDT"
[5] "2010-12-22 PST"

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```